# Store user IP, but make it non traceable

Tags: security, ip, sha, password-encryption

I am working on a project where users (in a given and relativity short time period) answers statements, and i would like to store the entries anonymously.

After the collection period is over, i would like to be able to run statics on the answers. But it is very important that the users answers can not be traced back to a specific user/ip.

The reason that i would still like to store ip, regardless of my desire for the users to be anonymously, is that i would like to exclude entries where the user (with malicious intent or by accident), take the same test multiple times in a short span.

I have ruled out using encryptions, as it is, to my limited knowledge, not possible to compare a large set of encrypted strings like that.

My currently self proposed method is then to store: The user agent, a session identifier and a hashed ip address.

Regarding to the hashing method, i am thinking to use sha512 where the ip is prepended with a 16 character long salt (same salt for all entries).

I know that when hashing simple and common strings, that sha512 and other hashing methods can be broken with tools like: http://md5decrypt.net/en/Sha512/ and good old brute forcing.

My idea to then guarantee user anonymity, is that after the collection period is over, i will delete the salt. Making it (to my knowledge) near impossible to brute force the hash. Even if a malicious party got hand on my source code.

I know it seems like a low tech solution, and that party of the security is based on my own action of actually deleting, where i en theory could forget or change my mind. But it is the only solution i could come up with.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't hash the IP's, HMAC them. That's conceptually the same than what you want to do, but cryptographically robust.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code

Comment: Thank you. 
But as fare as i can see, if my source code is breached and the HMAC key therefor is visible. With HMAC it is still "simply" a matter of running through all possible ips and make a plain ip to HMAC table?

Comment: the secret for the HMAC must not be in your source code (it is a secret...) but in some configuration file. it plays the same role as the "salt" of your explanation. at the end of the collection period, you can delete that secret.